# error Command failed with signal "SIGABRT" When running npm run sass-lint

Tags: node.js, npm, scss-lint, sass-lint

So I installed `scss-lint` with Atom and `npm -g sass-lint`

When I run `npm run sass-lint` I get this strange error message:

I'm trying to run `scss-lint` in the terminal, however can't find documentation on what the command is...

```
yarn run v1.0.2
$ "/Users/leongaban/projects/mythor/node_modules/.bin/sass-lint"

<--- Last few GCs --->

   12182 ms: Mark-sweep 1386.7 (1429.9) -> 1386.7 (1435.9) MB, 1461.1 / 0.0 ms (+ 0.1 ms in 162 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms) [allocation failure] [scavenge might not succeed].
   13882 ms: Mark-sweep 1392.3 (1435.9) -> 1392.3 (1435.9) MB, 1698.0 / 0.0 ms (+ 0.1 ms in 90 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms) [allocation failure] [scavenge might not succeed].


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: semi-space copy, fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::AllocateTargetObject(v8::internal::HeapObject*, v8::internal::HeapObject**) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject*) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::VisitLiveObjects(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*, v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::HeapObjectVisitor*, v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::IterationMode) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::PageParallelJob<v8::internal::EvacuationJobTraits>::Task::RunInternal() [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuatePagesInParallel() [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceAndCandidates() [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
13: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
14: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, char const*, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
15: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
16: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node]
17: 0x19d1ab079a7
18: 0x19d1b117952
19: 0x19d1b175ae6
error Command failed with signal "SIGABRT".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Figured it out, needed this:

`"test-scsslint": "./node_modules/.bin/sass-lint 'client/styles/**/*.scss' -v -q",`

Comment: Can you please add some clarification as to why this fixed it?

Comment: Unsure as this was 4 years ago now... this should no longer be an issue with any SASS react.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the Node.js memory when you run the server like this:

```
package.json ...

{
  "scripts": {
     "sass-lint": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/sass-lint"
  },
}
```